# Definition of the partial second derivatuve(2nd order)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

When I checked my Calculus note, there was a weird  thing

In note, it said

Let $f(x,y)$  and $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, Here the $f_y = {\partial f \over \partial y}$

$f_{xy}(a,b)$ = $\lim \limits_{h \to 0} {f_y(a+h,b)-f_y(a,b) \over h}$

But, In my thought this is a false because  $\lim \limits_{h \to 0} {f_y(a+h,b)-f_y(a,b) \over h}$ is a defintion of the $f_{yx}(a,b)$ not the $f_{xy}(a,b)$. So my conclusion is it is a typo.

Am I right?

Any comment always welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Note:  there can be [symmetry of second derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner, Thanks for your comment. But to claim symmetry(Clairaut's theorem), I've known, it need condition that both $f_{xy} $and $f_{yx}$ continuous. But the note doesn't have any condition about that at all.

Comment: $f_{xy}$ means 'first differentiate with respect to $x$, then $y$'. So yes, it's a typo.